# Sorting an array by name alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have an array of `"Brand Products"` that I am trying to sort into alphabetical order based on their `name` after they are obtained from the database, the list is currently populated using this:

```
    protected override object[] GetCollection()
    {
        Brand brand = ItemLocator.LocateItem(this.Parent, typeof(Brand)) as Brand;

        ICriteria criteria = CoreHttpModule.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product));
        criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("Brand", brand));
        criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("IsVisibleOnWebsite", true));

        IList<Product> productList = criteria.List<Product>();

        IList<Product> filteredLroductList = new List<Product>();

        for (int i = 0; i < productList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (productList[i].Parent != null)
            {
                filteredLroductList.Add(productList[i]);
            }
        }

        object[] filteredProductListArray = new object[filteredLroductList.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < filteredLroductList.Count; i++)
        {
            filteredProductListArray.SetValue(filteredLroductList[i], i);
        }

             return filteredProductListArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in a single linq expression.

```
products[] productList = criteria.List<Product>()
                                  .Where(p => p.Parent != null)
                                  .OrderBy((p => p.Name)
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comple code.

```
protected override object[] GetCollection()
{
    Brand brand = ItemLocator.LocateItem(this.Parent, typeof(Brand)) as Brand;

    ICriteria criteria = CoreHttpModule.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product));
    criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("Brand", brand));
    criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("IsVisibleOnWebsite", true));

    products[] productList = criteria.List<Product>()
                                         .Where(p => p.Parent != null)
                                         .OrderBy((p => p.Name)
                                         .ToArray();
    return productList;
}
```

Comment: I actually used an alternative method by doing most of it in NHibernate :) but thank for you the answer and I am sure this will help other people with similar issues!

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply replace the 2<sup>nd</sup> half of your method by:

```
return filteredProductList.OrderBy(f => f.BrandName).ToArray();
```

*assuming that `BrandName` is what you want to order by*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected override object[] GetCollection()
{
    Brand brand = ItemLocator.LocateItem(this.Parent, typeof(Brand)) as Brand;

    ICriteria criteria = CoreHttpModule.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product));
    criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("Brand", brand));
    criteria.Add(NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("IsVisibleOnWebsite", true));

    return criteria.List<Product>()
        .Where(x => x.Parent != null)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: How about filtering by `Parent != null`, as in the original?

Answer (score 0):

Something roughly like this, depending on your types:

`var products = from p in GetCollection() orderby p.ProductName select p;`

Answer (score 0):

If you keep it as a List, then you can use linq against the collection...

mylist = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();